# How do I get spectacle-code-slide working on Windows?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spectacle

I have installed Node on a Windows 10 machine. Then did `npm install spectacle` from the node command prompt. Finally downloaded the spectacle-code-slide zip file. Moved into the folder, did `npm install` and `npm start`. I get the following:

`npm ERR: missing script: start`.

Obviously, I am missing something. What is it? Note: I am a complete noob!

Edit: I tried the process outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800547/spectacle-code-slide-not-rendering) without success.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you don't have `start` script in your package.json. Read about scripts [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values).

When you run `npm instal spectacle` you install `spectacle` as a package into `node_modules` folder. So you don't have any scripts in your package.json except those you add there yourself.

I've actually never used `spectacle`, but I suppose you better use their [`spectacle-boilerplate`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle-boilerplate/) (instead of doing `npm instal spectacle`). You need to clone (via git) or download that repository locally. And then you will have their package.json with `start` script in it.

Comment: Hi @GProst, I tried that too. But how do I install `spectacle-code-slide` on top of `spectacle-boilerplate` ?

Comment: Simply. Just run `spectacle-code-slide` in the root folder of downloaded `spectacle-boilerplate` project. And it will be installed here. `spectacle-boilerplate` project is just a helper template, it has `spectacule` installed in it and some other packages (you can see it in their package.json) so you don't need to install them by our own. I think you should read more about how npm works and more about what is package.json is. After you consolidate knowledge it will be much easier to understand what is going on here =)

Comment: Agreed, I need to read up on npm etc. But can someone walk me through this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide some helpful `npm` tutorials since I studied it on Russian resources. But I'm sure there are a lot of them in the web. When learning something new in IT field I prefer youtube video tutorials for a start and then articles and documentations.

Comment: What I mean is can somebody point out the steps needed to successfully get the spectacle code slides up and running.